# Codeigniter failed to upload and can't get file_name

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I using CI tank_auth library to allow user to edit their profiles in one time, now I was stuck at picture (avatar) upload, I want user to upload their picture and store the filename in table, I tried to get the filename and update in the table, but has no success and the specific field is leave blank.

OK, I tried to check whether controller has `hold` the selected file, I use flashdata to check what is response after uploaded, what I saw is `filename:`, and the `$image_data['file_name']` which is expected doesn't shown, even the file is not uploaded to the specific path.

I wonder what's wrong in my codes, and I've been spent several hours for solution but didn't get any clues.

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    if(!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('/auth/login');

    }else{

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|min_length[5]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('country', 'Country', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website', 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[30]');

                    // Here I do upload file check

        if (!empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {

            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $image_data = $this->upload->data('photo');

            $this->session->set_flashdata('see', 'filename: '.$image_data['file_name']);

        }else{

            $this->session->set_flashdata('see', 'where is my file?');
        }


        $data['errors'] = array();

        if($this->form_validation->run()) { // validation ok

            if(!is_null($data = $this->tank_auth->update_user(
                $this->form_validation->set_value('name'),
                $this->form_validation->set_value('country'),
                $this->form_validation->set_value('website'),
                $this->form_validation->set_value($image_data['file_name'])
            ))) { // success

                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Profile has been updated');
                redirect(current_url());
            }

        }else{

            $errors = $this->tank_auth->get_error_message();
            foreach($errors as $k => $v) $data['errors'][$k] = $this->lang->line($v);
        }

        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $profile = $this->users->get_profile_by_id($user_id);

        $data = array(
            'uname' => $profile->name,
            'ucountry' => $profile->country,
            'uwebsite' => $profile->website,
            'uavatar' => $profile->photo
        );
    }

    $data['title'] = $this->session->userdata('name').'\'s Account';

    $this->load->view('header', $data);
    $this->load->view('my_account', $data);
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php
$photo = array(
    'name' => 'photo',
    'id' => 'photo',
    'size' => 30
);

if(($this->session->flashdata('see'))){
    echo '
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="margin:5px 0;">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type="button">×</button>
            '.$this->session->flashdata('see').'
        </div>';
}
?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart($this->uri->uri_string()); ?>
<table border="0">
  .
  . // blah blah info fields here
  .
  <tr>
    <td>
    <div><?php echo form_label('Photo', $photo['id']); ?></div>
    <div><?php echo form_upload($photo); ?></div>
    <div class="field_error"><?php echo form_error($photo['name']); ?><?php echo isset($errors[$photo['name']])?$errors[$photo['name']]:''; ?></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div style="padding:20px 0;"><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save'); ?></div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the following line

```
$this->upload->do_upload("image")
```

Add the above code before,

```
$image_data = $this->upload->data('photo');
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the uploaded file to the server with CI, then try this

```
$path_to_file = $config['upload_path'].$image_data['file_name'];
write_file($config['upload_path'].$image_data['file_name'], .$image_data['file_name']);
```

Also, make sure that you load the file helper too as follows

```
$this->load->helper('file');
```